# Howto activate statistics for an average value in Loxone

Tags: logic, loxone-miniserver

It's not possible to activate the statistics right in the app for an average. I want to activate statistics for an average value of 3 humidity sensors.

Is there a way to realize without external applications like Loxberry or InfluxDB/Grafana?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by adding a virtual status in your Loxone Config.

- Just add the element
- Connect the `Avg` output of the average element with the virtual status element input `I`
- Activate the statistics checkbox in the virtual status element

[image: setup example]

[image: properties of virtual status element]

---

There is also a benefit of this setup: the stats are kept saved if a sensor or logic gets updated.